# org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: postgresql, types, syntax, casting, prepared-statement

> : org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [update tableA set flag= ?  where c_id=? and v_id=? and notification=?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = character varying
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Tried different ways of type casts, but still not working, appreciate a apt solution for this.
Thanks,

Comment: Well, "*operator does not exist: boolean = character varying*" is pretty obvious. You can't compare a boolean value with a string.

Comment: `column = ?`  and `PreparedStatement.setBoolean(...)`